# New reject reasons for suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I thought about pre-defined reject reasons for suggested edits, and here are two I think might be helpful:

### Edit changes code of question

As discussed in this meta post, [editing the code of a question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/should-you-edit-someone-elses-code-in-a-question) is not recommended. But right now, there does not exist a pre-defined reject reason for this rule. I think it would be good to have it for

- new people who maybe don't know that this would be a valid reject reason
- people who do not want to write a custom reject reason each time

### Edit is too minor [for an old question]

It seems that the general consensus in this question about [minor edits](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/when-are-edits-too-minor-to-approve#2607) is that there are at least some circumstances in which an edit might be considered too minor to approve. If that turns out to be the case, a pre-defined reject reason for this case might be helpful.

Comment: You beat me to making this request.

Answer (score 4):

Well, Stack Exhange [just got rid of the "Too Minor" reject button](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/?cb=1), so my guess is that's out.

I am 100% behind getting a reject reason for "Edit changed the code to be reviewed". Almost every time (to my recollection) that I reject an edit, it's because a well meaning person reformatted the code. We reject those edits because formatting is a valid subject for review. It would be nice to have a standardized rejection at the click of a button instead of typing out something (inevitably different) each time.

That said, I have no idea if it's even possible for an edit rejection reason to be added for just one site.